# SQL Join Query for 3 tables not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm new to SQL and need some help.
I have the following 3 tables Tables in my database.

```
STUDENT Table whose tuple has the following format:
{StuID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, EmailID}

COURSES Table whose tuple has the following format:
{CourseID, CourseName, CreditHours, CourseDescription}

TAKEN_COURSES Table whose tuple has the following format:
{ID, StuID, CourseID, Semester, Year}.
```

Now I want to display all courses taken by students in the following format:

```
LastName FirstName MiddleName Course1   Course2
May         Alice    Mary      Math     Science
Wood        Bob      Adams     Physics  History
```

It is known in advance each student can take atmost 2 courses only. If a student takes just 1 course, the other entry can be blank.

I joined the 3 tables as:

```
Select Student Student.LName, Student.FName, Student.MiddleName, Courses.CourseName from Student INNER JOIN (Courses INNERJOIN TakenCourses ON Courses.CourseID=TakenCourses.CourseID) ON Student.StuID = TakenCourses.CourseID
```

This gives me the following:

```
LastName FirstName MiddleName CourseName
May         Alice    Mary      Math     
May         Alice    Mary      Science
Wood        Bob      Adams     Physics  
Wood        Bob      Adams     History
```

But I do not want that. I want all courses to show up one after the other in a single tuple and I'm really struggling to achieve that. Any suggestions about what needs to be done?

Comment: Sure. Actually stack overflow suggested me to add an additional tag so I added that. I'm using sql-server so I'm going to add just that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with *aggregation*, specifically because there are two values.  Your query is most of the way there:

```
Select s.LName, s.FName, s.MiddleName, 
       min(c.CourseName) as course1,
       (case when min(c.CourseName) <> max(c.CourseName) then max(c.CourseName)
        end) as course2
from Student s join
     TakenCourses tc
     on s.StuID = tc.CourseID
     Courses c 
     on c.CourseID = tc.CourseID
group by s.LName, s.FName, s.MiddleName;
```

Why is aggregation useful?  Well, you have multiple rows per student and you want only one.  In such cases, `group by` is often the right approach.

Also note the use of table aliases, which simplify writing and reading the query.  Also, it is best to avoid parentheses in the `from` clause, when they are not necessary.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the min, max clauses in here achieve?

Comment: @paratrooper . . . If you are not familiar with `GROUP BY`, you should learn what the aggregation functions do.  This is a very basic part of the SQL language.